# Rails Mail gem finding out recipient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mail-gem

I collect all Mails from a pop server with Mail.all

```
 @currentmails = Mail.all
  # Über alle Mails im Postfach Iterieren
  @currentmails.each do | mail |
    puts mail.to
  end
```

But mail.to doesn't work ... I got this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for ["mail@HOST.de"]:Mail::AddressContainer
```

Mail Recipient (to) Looks like this:

```
<To: <mail@HOST.de>>
```

Comment: What code (module and line number) does that error message point to? Is it really pointing to your `puts mail.to`? I don't see a `gsub` call in the code sample you're showing.

Comment: Yes its this line. I dont know from wäre the gsub comes. I dont use it

Comment: Which mail gem are you using exactly?

Comment: Gem  mail is added in gemfile

Comment: This gem: https://github.com/mikel/mail

Comment: It works. I have to cast it to string. `mail.to.to_s` is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mail.to.to_s`

is the solution of the problem.